# I need to hide a button when another button is pressed

Tags: android

With the following code I am getting Null Pointer Exception error.But without using View I am getting proper output without hiding the buttons.(that is just disabling)
My xml file is:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/start_track"
    android:onClick="start"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/stop_track"
    android:onClick="stop" 

    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"/>
```

and my activity code is :

```
public void start(View v1)
{

    schedular = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

    Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this, "Tracking Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    updateLocation();

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setEnabled(false);
    findViewById(R.id.button2).setEnabled(true);

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.button2).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


}

public void stop(View v2)
{

    Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this, "Tracking Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    schedular.shutdown();

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setEnabled(true);
    findViewById(R.id.button2).setEnabled(false);   

    findViewById(R.id.button1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.button2).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

kindly help me. I tried this code by removing disabling code lines.Still I am getting Null Pointer Exception error.

Comment: why dont you declare button b = (button) findview.... and then do b.setVisibility(...)?

Comment: Kindly post your logcat , also why are you passing the view as an argument when you are not using the View in any of the methods .And I will second @Mihai on initializing the button once in the onCreate of the activity.
Also I would say that if you are trying button A to hide on click of Button B, and button B to hide on click of Button A this can be handled through the respective onclickListeners for each button.

Comment: These 2 methods, `start` and `stop` lie in the Activity where you set content view? Or are they in a fragment?

Comment: feels like that it is the whole activity-code...

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to stay with one button and change text on click:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/start_track"
    android:onClick="doSth"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

and

```
private boolean clicked = false;

public void doSth(View v1)
{
    if(clicked) {

        Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this, "Tracking Stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        schedular.shutdown();

        findViewById(R.id.button1).setText("Start tracking");

        clicked = false;
    } else {

        schedular = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        Toast.makeText(WelcomeActivity.this, "Tracking Started",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        updateLocation();

        findViewById(R.id.button1).setText("Stop tracking");

    }
}
```

Comment: No it is not working for me. I directly used findViewById(R.id.button).setEnabled(false); Now it is working. Anyway, thanks for your help.